# d3: force directed graph: node filtering

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I was going through the following post:

[highlight selected node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-js-force-directed-g)

[image]

Really a nice solution... I am a newbie to d3 and fascinated with its flexibility. I am facing problem at one point. Instead of filtering the nodes on mouseover, I want to filter it on the basis of text entered (node name or id) in a html textbox. Any idea how to achieve this??

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I actually had to do something like this for a project at work. The solution I came up with was to give each node a boolean property which I called isInFilter.

Once the user enters in the text, process it and then loop through all the nodes and assign isInFilter for each node either TRUE or FALSE. Then, your condition for the node displaying (or doing whatever transition you want to do) simply becomes a check on the isInFilter property.

Comment: Could you show an example of this? I'm stuck because I'm using `d3.json()` to get data so I have to be within that block to get access to nodes/links/graph, but can't call nested function from html.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by being stuck - you can pass the data anywhere you want from within there.

Comment: disregard, I figured it out. Thank you for your response, though.