# Dynamically change opacity of links and nodes in d3 force graph based on radio button filter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radio-button, force-layout

I have [a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qvco2Ljy/72/). When a filter radio button is selected, I want it to dynamically change the opacity of elements and links based on their rating (the node objects have a `rating` property with an integer value).

[image: node graph example with filter]

**Can't simply use onchange/onclick due to function being nested**

When I bind a JS function to the onchange or onclick method for the radio buttons, it can't find the function because it is inside the `d3.json(){};` block (the example has the data separated to make it work on fiddle but this line is commented out). If I don't put the function inside that block, it doesn't have access to the links and nodes, but if it is inside, the onchange/onclick can't find it. I can't call a nested function from the html side since it is out of scope.

**Can't add as attribute to existing input radio buttons (doesn't work)**

I then tried dynamically adding the onchange and onclick events (I tried both ways) to the input from the JS side but that didn't appear to work (perhaps I did it wrong).

**How to do this?**

I've tried getting #1 to work below but I'm effectively stuck on #1, which makes me think I'm approaching the problem the wrong way. There has to be another way to do this.

1. Figure out how to call a function inside the `d3.json(){}` block when an `onchange` or `onclick` event is fired from a radio button.
2. Figure out how to change the opacity of nodes and links based on their data.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14600967/) is a similar issue, but there is no example so I can't see how to apply it. I *do* have a field to filter on in my node objects, but can't figure out how to do so dynamically in response to a radio button selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a reference to the variables you care about at a scope outside your `.json` callback.  In this case it's probably `link` and `node`:

```
var link, node;
d3.json('map2.json', function(error, graph) { 

   ...

   link = container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")

   ...

   node = container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")

   ...

});
```

You can then use these is your change event of your radio buttons:

```
d3.selectAll("input[name=filter]").on("change", function(d){

  // value of selected radio
  var value = this.value;
  // everybody
  node.style("opacity", 1);
  // those that aren't dim
  if (value !== "all"){
    value = +this.value;
    node.filter(function(d){
      return d.rating != value;
    })
    .style("opacity", "0.5");
  }

});
```

---

Running code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yr1WKeuSXX6Ij0nfvEYu?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, Mark. This got me 95% of the way there! I appreciate it. Now I just need to figure out how to make the links opaque for these also.