# D3: Highlight connected/adjacent nodes

Tags: d3.js, highlight, force-layout

So I have a force directed graph, and I would like that when I hover a node, all the connected nodes and links gets highlighted ( the stroke color would change until the mouse would leave the node )

This would help the navigation of really crowded graphs.

How can I find connected links ( and connected nodes ) when inside of the on() function ?

```
var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
.on("mouseover",function(d) {
    [...] //Find attached link, and node, and force a stroke color
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    [...] //Restore previous color
});
```

Comment: mbostock answered this himself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-js-force-directed-g

Comment: I voted for question close as duplicate, thanks.