# D3 highlight selected node, and its links to parent and ancestors in a force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, hover, parent, highlight, force-layout

I would like to highlight the links and nodes to the parent node in a graph when the child node is hovered. I took inspiration from The New York Times ['Paths to the white house'](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/11/02/us/politics/paths-to-the-white-house.html):

[image]

I have seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857806/apply-several-mouseover-events-to-neighboring-connected-nodes) with [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/QajDa/1/) using:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
   .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.name + " " + d.location; })
    .call(force.drag)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        // if(isConnected(d, o)) {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 6);               
        var nodeNeighbors = graph.links.filter(function(link) {
            return link.source.index === d.index || link.target.index === d.index;
        })
        .map(function(link) {
             return link.source.index === d.index ? link.target.index : link.source.index;
        });               
        svg.selectAll('circle').style('stroke', 'gray');
        svg.selectAll('circle').filter(function(node) {
            return nodeNeighbors.indexOf(node.index) > -1;
        })
        // }
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        //   I would like to insert an if statement to do all of
        //   these things to the connected nodes
        // if(isConnected(d, o)) {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 6); 
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "orange");
        // }
    })
    .on("mouseout",  function(d) { 
        // if(isConnected(d, o)) {
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 1.5); 
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "gray"); 
        // }
    });
```

Though they're using source and target, I wonder if it's also possible, and how it would be done, with a network diagram (force-directed graph) using parent and children?

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar by adapting the functions found in [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/hive/). The trick is to build selections that work on only the links you'd like to highlight. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
function linkMouseover(d){
  chart.selectAll(".node").classed("active", function(p) { return d3.select(this).classed("active") || p === d.source || p === d.target; });
          }
// Highlight the node and connected links on mouseover.
function nodeMouseover(d) {
 chart.selectAll(".link").classed("active", function(p) { return d3.select(this).classed("active") || p.source === d || p.target === d; });
            chart.selectAll(".link.active").each(function(d){linkMouseover(d)})
            d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
          }
```

This [force-directed example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) uses the terminology source and target—I don't imagine there's much distinction between source-target and parent-child. You should be able to make it work by editing the above, such that the `.each()` and `.classed()` callbacks operate only on the highlighted node, its (multiple generations of) children, and links between them.

Answer (score -1):

```
Complete code from fiddle:
var graph = {"nodes": [
    {"name": "Betty",  "size": 12, "company": "X", "location": "ChicagoIL"},
    {"name": "Frank",  "size": 12, "company": "Y", "location": "NewYorkNY"},
    {"name": "Jim",    "size": 12, "company": "Y", "location": "LosAngelesCA"},
    {"name": "Sally",  "size": 12, "company": "Z", "location": "TorontoON"},
    {"name": "Tom",    "size": 12, "company": "X", "location": "ChicagoIL"},
    {"name": "GroupA", "size": 18, "company": "T", "location": "x"},
    {"name": "GroupB", "size": 18, "company": "T", "location": "x"}],
  "links": [
    {"source": 2, "target": 5,  "bond": 1},
    {"source": 3, "target": 5,  "bond": 2},
    {"source": 4, "target": 5,  "bond": 1},
    {"source": 0, "target": 6,  "bond": 1},
    {"source": 1, "target": 6,  "bond": 2},
    {"source": 4, "target": 6,  "bond": 1}],
  "locs": [
    {"lat": 40.7142, "long":  -74.0064, "location": "NewYorkNY"},
    {"lat": 34.0522, "long": -118.2428, "location": "LosAngelesCA"},
    {"lat": 43.6481, "long":  -79.4042, "location": "TorontoON"},
    {"lat": 41.8500, "long":  -87.6500, "location": "ChicagoIL"}]};

    var width = 250;
    var height = 250;
    var padding = 20;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var radius = d3.scale.sqrt()
        .range([0, 7]);

    var scale = d3.scale.linear();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .charge(-400)
        .linkStrength(3)
        .linkDistance(function(d) {
            return radius(d.source.size) + radius(d.target.size) + (30 / (2*d.bond-1))
            ; });

        // network diagram stuff

        force
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "link");

        link.append("line")
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return (d.bond * 2 - 1) * 3 + "px"; });

        link.filter(function(d) { return d.bond > 1; }).append("line")
            .attr("class", "separator");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.name + " " + d.location; })
            .call(force.drag)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
                // I would like to insert an if statement to do all of these things to the connected nodes
                // if(isConnected(d, o)) {
                    d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 6); 

                    // Figure out the neighboring node id's with brute strength because the graph is small
                    var nodeNeighbors = graph.links.filter(function(link) {
                        // Filter the list of links to only those links that have our target 
                        // node as a source or target
                        return link.source.index === d.index || link.target.index === d.index;})
                    .map(function(link) {
                        // Map the list of links to a simple array of the neighboring indices - this is
                        // technically not required but makes the code below simpler because we can use         
                        // indexOf instead of iterating and searching ourselves.
                        return link.source.index === d.index ? link.target.index : link.source.index; });

                    // Reset all circles - we will do this in mouseout also
                    svg.selectAll('circle').style('stroke', 'gray');

                    // now we select the neighboring circles and apply whatever style we want. 
                    // Note that we could also filter a selection of links in this way if we want to 
                    // Highlight those as well
                    svg.selectAll('circle').filter(function(node) {
                        // I filter the selection of all circles to only those that hold a node with an
                        // index in my listg of neighbors
                        return nodeNeighbors.indexOf(node.index) > -1;
                    })
                    .style('stroke', 'orange');

                    d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "orange"); 
                    d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "20px sans-serif");
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke-width", 6);
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke", "orange");
                    d3.selectAll("text." + d.location).style("font", "20px sans-serif");
                    d3.selectAll("tr." + d.name).style("background-color", "orange");
                    //}
                })
            .on("mouseout",  function(d) { 
                // if(isConnected(d, o)) {
                    svg.selectAll('circle').style('stroke', 'gray');
                    d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 1.5); 
                    //d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "gray"); 
                    d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "12px sans-serif");
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke-width", 1.5);
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke", "gray");
                    d3.selectAll("text." + d.location).style("font", "12px sans-serif");
                    d3.selectAll("tr." + d.name).style("background-color", "white");
                    //}
                });

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return radius(d.size); })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        var linkedByIndex = {};
            graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
                linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
                });

        function isConnected(a, b) {
            return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
            }

        function tick() {
            link.selectAll("line")
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
            node.attr("transform", function(d) { 
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
            }


        // map stuff

        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(graph.locs, function(d) { return d.long; }), d3.max(graph.locs, function(d) { return d.long; })])
            .range([padding, width-(4*padding)]);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([d3.min(graph.locs, function(d) { return d.lat; }), d3.max(graph.locs, function(d) { return d.lat; })])
            .range([height-padding, padding]);

        var mapit = svg2.selectAll(".mapit")
            .data(graph.locs)
            .enter().append("g")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
                d3.select(this).select("rect").style("stroke-width", 6); 
                d3.select(this).select("rect").style("stroke", "orange"); 
                d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "20px sans-serif");
                d3.selectAll("g." + d.location + " circle").style("stroke-width", 6); 
                d3.selectAll("g." + d.location + " circle").style("stroke", "orange"); 
                d3.selectAll("g." + d.location + " text").style("font", "20px sans-serif");
                d3.selectAll("tr." + d.location).style("background-color", "orange");
                })
            .on("mouseout",  function(d) { 
                d3.select(this).select("rect").style("stroke-width", 1.5); 
                d3.select(this).select("rect").style("stroke", "gray"); 
                d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "12px sans-serif");
                d3.selectAll("g." + d.location + " circle").style("stroke-width", 1.5); 
                d3.selectAll("g." + d.location + " circle").style("stroke", "gray"); 
                d3.selectAll("g." + d.location + " text").style("font", "12px sans-serif");
                d3.selectAll("tr." + d.location).style("background-color", "white");
                });

        mapit.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.long); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.lat); })
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("width", 20)
            .attr("fill", "gray")
            .attr("stroke-width", "1.5")
            .attr("stroke", "gray")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return d.location ;});

        mapit.append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.long); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.lat) -5; })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "12px")
            .attr("fill", "black")
            .text(function(d) { return d.location; })
            .attr("class", function(d) { return d.location ;});

        // table stuff

        function tabulate(tdata, columns) {
            var table = d3.select("body").append("table"),
                thead = table.append("thead"),
                tbody = table.append("tbody");
            thead.append("tr").selectAll("th")
                .data(columns)
                .enter().append("th")
                .text(function(column) { return column; });

            var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(tdata)
                .enter().append("tr")
                .attr("class", function(d) { return d.name + " " + d.location ;})
                .on("mouseover", function(d){
                    d3.select(this).style("background-color", "orange");
                    d3.selectAll("g." + d.name + " circle").style("stroke-width", 6);
                    d3.selectAll("g." + d.name + " circle").style("stroke", "orange");
                    d3.selectAll("g." + d.name + " text").style("font", "20px sans-serif");
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke-width", 6);
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke", "orange");
                    d3.selectAll("text." + d.location).style("font", "20px sans-serif");
                    })
                .on("mouseout", function(d){
                    d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white");
                    d3.selectAll("g." + d.name + " circle").style("stroke-width", 1);
                    d3.selectAll("g." + d.name + " circle").style("stroke", "gray");
                    d3.selectAll("g." + d.name + " text").style("font", "12px sans-serif");
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke-width", 1.5);
                    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke", "gray");
                    d3.selectAll("text." + d.location).style("font", "12px sans-serif");
                    });

            var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
                .data(function(row) {
                    return columns.map(function(column) {
                        return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                        });
                    })
                .enter().append("td")
                .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
            return table;
            }

        var subdata = graph.nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.location!="x"; });

        var myTable = tabulate(subdata, ["name", "company", "location"]);

        myTable.selectAll("thead th")
            .text(function(column) {
                return column.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + column.substr(1);
            });

        myTable.selectAll("tbody tr")
            .sort(function(a, b) {
                return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name);
            });
```

Comment: Need some description