# d3js force directed - On hover to node, highlight/colourup linked nodes and links?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, highlight, force-layout

I have force directed graph with 4 types of nodes and two types of links. One type of node (the small blue one) I'm using as "connection node" between two bigger nodes.

on mouseover node, it gets bigger, but also I wanna colour up "connections" to this node in different color. So whey you hover over a node... all links and little "connection nodes" gets in the different color, so you can know to which other bigger node is this one hovered connected.

You can see my situation on following link: http://jsfiddle.net/2pdxz/

For example: If you hover up `Google` node,  links to `Yahoo` with "connection" node gets highlighted and links to `CDO` and `CTO` gets highlighted

I've tried to add this part of code:

```
function fade(opacity) 
{  link.style("opacity", function(d) {
   return d.source === d || d.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                });
            
            }
```

which I picked up from some other question with the similar problem but I don't know how this could actually help me, because I'm noob about d3js.

The exact code looks like this

Script:

```
var data = {"nodes":[
                            {"name":"YHO", "full_name":"Yahoo", "type":1, "slug": "www.yahoo.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},
                            {"name":"GGL", "full_name":"Google", "type":2, "slug": "www.google.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},
                            {"name":"BNG", "full_name":"Bing", "type":2, "slug": "www.bing.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},
                            {"name":"YDX", "full_name":"Yandex", "type":2, "slug": "www.yandex.com", "entity":"company", "img_hrefD":"", "img_hrefL":""},
                            
                            {"name":"Desc1", "type":4, "slug": "", "entity":"description"},
                            {"name":"Desc2", "type":4, "slug": "", "entity":"description"},
                            {"name":"Desc4", "type":4, "slug": "", "entity":"description"},
                            
                            {"name":"CEO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Jim", "snd_name":"Bean", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                            {"name":"ATT", "prefix":"Ms.", "fst_name":"Jenna", "snd_name":"Jameson", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                            {"name":"CTO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Lucky", "snd_name":"Luke", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                            {"name":"CDO", "prefix":"Ms.", "fst_name":"Pamela", "snd_name":"Anderson", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                            {"name":"CEO", "prefix":"Mr.", "fst_name":"Nacho", "snd_name":"Vidal", "type":3, "slug": "", "entity":"employee"},
                        ], 
                "links":[
                            {"source":0,"target":4,"value":1,"distance":5},
                            {"source":0,"target":5,"value":1,"distance":5},
                            {"source":0,"target":6,"value":1,"distance":5},
                            
                            {"source":1,"target":4,"value":1,"distance":5},
                            {"source":2,"target":5,"value":1,"distance":5},
                            {"source":3,"target":6,"value":1,"distance":5},
                            
                            {"source":7,"target":3,"value":10,"distance":6},
                            {"source":8,"target":3,"value":10,"distance":6},
                            {"source":9,"target":1,"value":10,"distance":6},
                            {"source":10,"target":1,"value":10,"distance":6},
                            {"source":11,"target":2,"value":10,"distance":6},
                            ]
                   }    
            
            
            
        var w = 560,
            h = 500,
            radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0, 312000]).range(["10", "50"]);
        
        var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
            
            //vis.append("defs").append("marker")
            //.attr("id", "arrowhead")
            //.attr("refX", 22 + 3) /*must be smarter way to calculate shift*/
            //.attr("refY", 2)
            //.attr("markerWidth", 6)
            //.attr("markerHeight", 4)
            //.attr("orient", "auto")
            //.append("path")
                //.attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z"); //this is actual shape for arrowhead
        
        //d3.json(data, function(json) {
            var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
                .nodes(data.nodes)
                .links(data.links)
                .linkDistance(function(d) { return (d.distance*10); })
                //.friction(0.5)
                .charge(-250)
                .size([w, h])
                .start();
        
        
        
            var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
                .data(data.links)
                .enter().append("svg:line")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return "link" + d.value +""; })
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
                .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
                                                    if (d.value == 1) {return "url(#arrowhead)"}
                                                    else    { return " " }
                                                ;});

            function fade(opacity) {
                
                    link.style("opacity", function(d) {
                        return d.source === d || d.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                    });
                
                }
                
                
            function openLink() {
                return function(d) {
                    var url = "";
                    if(d.slug != "") {
                        url = d.slug
                    } //else if(d.type == 2) {
                        //url = "clients/" + d.slug
                    //} else if(d.type == 3) {
                        //url = "agencies/" + d.slug
                    //}
                    window.open("//"+url)
                }
            }
                
        
            
        
            var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(data.nodes)
              .enter().append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(force.drag);
        
            
            node.append("circle")
                .attr("class", function(d){ return "node type"+d.type})
                .attr("r",function(d){if(d.entity == "description"){ return 6 } else { return 18 }})
                //.on("mouseover", expandNode);
                //.style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.type); })
                
                        
        
            node.append("svg:image")
                .attr("class", function(d){ return "circle img_"+d.name })
                .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefD})
                .attr("x", "-36px")
                .attr("y", "-36px")
                .attr("width", "70px")
                .attr("height", "70px")
                .on("click", openLink())
                .on("mouseover", function (d) { if(d.entity == "company")
                                                    {
                        d3.select(this).attr("width", "90px")
                                        .attr("x", "-46px")
                                        .attr("y", "-36.5px")
                                       .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefL});                           
                                                    }
                    })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) { if(d.entity == "company")
                                                {
                        d3.select(this).attr("width", "70px")
                                        .attr("x", "-36px")
                                        .attr("y", "-36px")
                                       .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_hrefD});
                                                }
                    });    
                    
        
            node.append("text")
                .attr("class", function(d){ return "nodetext title_"+d.name })
                .attr("dx", 0)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("font-size","10px")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill", "white")
                .text(function(d) { if (d.entity != "description"){return d.name} });
                
                

            node.on("mouseover", function (d) {
                if (d.entity == "company"){   
                    d3.select(this).select('text')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(300)
                        .text(function(d){
                                return d.full_name;
                            })
                        .style("font-size","15px")
                        
                }
                else if(d.entity == "employee"){
                    var asdf = d3.select(this);
                    asdf.select('text').remove();
                    
                    asdf.append("text")
                                .text(function(d){return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name })
                                .attr("class","nodetext")
                                .attr("dx", 0)
                                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                                .style("font-size","5px")
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                .style("fill", "white")
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .style("font-size","12px");
                    
                    asdf.append("text").text(function(d){return d.snd_name })
                                .attr("class","nodetext")
                                .attr("transform","translate(0, 12)")
                                .attr("dx", 0)
                                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                                .style("font-size","5px")
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                .style("fill", "white")
                                .transition()
                                .duration(300)
                                .style("font-size","12px");                                         
                }
                else {
                    d3.select(this).select('text')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(300)
                        .style("font-size","15px")
                }
                        
                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('image')
                        .attr("width", "90px")
                        .attr("x", "-46px")
                        .attr("y", "-36.5px")
                        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                            return d.img_hrefL
                            });               
                }
                
                if (d.entity == "company") {
                
                    d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                    .transition()
                                    .duration(300)
                                    .attr("r",28)
                                    
                }
                else if (d.entity == "employee"){
                    d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                    .transition()
                                    .duration(300)
                                    .attr("r",32)
                }
            })
            
             
             node.on("mouseout", function (d) {
                if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('text')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(300)
                        .text(function(d){return d.name;})
                        .style("font-size","10px")
                    }
                else if(d.entity == "employee"){
                    ///////////////////////////
                    // CHANGE
                    ///////////////////////////
                    
                    d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();
                    
                    //d3.select(this).select('text')
                    d3.select(this).append('text')
                        .text(function(d){return d.name;})
                        .style("font-size","14px")  
                        .attr("dx", 0)
                        .attr("dy", ".35em")
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .attr("class","nodetext")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(300)
                        .style("font-size","10px")
                    
                }
                else {
                    d3.select(this).select('text')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(300)
                        .style("font-size","10px")
                }
                        
                    
                 if (d.entity == "company") {
                    d3.select(this).select('image')
                        .attr("width", "70px")
                        .attr("x", "-36px")
                        .attr("y", "-36px")
                        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                        return d.img_hrefD
                    });
                }
                
                if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {
                
                    d3.select(this).select('circle')
                                    .transition()
                                    .duration(300)
                                    .attr("r",18)
                }
                
            });
        
            force.on("tick", function() {
              link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
        
              node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
            });
        //});
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.link10 { stroke: #ccc; stroke-width: 2px; stroke-dasharray: 3, 3; }
.link1 { stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px;}
.nodetext { pointer-events: none;}

.node.type1 {
  fill:#690011;
}
.node.type2 {
  fill:#BF0426;
}
.node.type3 {
  fill:#E5B96F;
}
.node.type4 {
  fill:#FFFFFF;
  stroke:#1695A3; 
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node.type5 {
    fill:#1BC9E0;
}

.node.type6 {
    fill:#E01B98;
}

image.circle {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.fadein{
display:none;
font-size:20px;
}

.rectD{
background-color:#000000;
width:70px;
height:30px
}

.rectL{
background-color:#000000;
width:90px;
height:30px
}
```

You can edit and see working example in my linked jsfiddle..

Any suggestion or help is welcome..

Comment: You need to think about how to identify the links and nodes that are to be highlighted. What properties do their data need to have?

Comment: I need to aim what nodes are linked to what dones via "links" in data... It's too abstract for me still

Comment: Nodes are linked if one of them is the source of a link and the other the target. You can get this information directly from the links, so all you need to do is iterate over them and check the source and target nodes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, honestly

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-js-force-directed-g)?

Comment: yea, I've found it earlier, I'm trying to sort my need with help of this one but till now I'm not successful so did not post anything further than this

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The way I solved this problem in my own project was to examine the links to see if their source or target properties matched the hovered node. This should be a step in the right direction.

```
// On node hover, examine the links to see if their
// source or target properties match the hovered node.
node.on('mouseover', function(d) {
  link.style('stroke-width', function(l) {
    if (d === l.source || d === l.target)
      return 4;
    else
      return 2;
    });
});

// Set the stroke width back to normal when mouse leaves the node.
node.on('mouseout', function() {
  link.style('stroke-width', 2);
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2pdxz/2/