# how to put the arrowheads on a D3 graph so that it shows the complete relationship over the network

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I am working on telecom project in which i have to show some churn customers who are connecting over a network i am using this api 
http://bl.ocks.org/samuelleach/5497403 
to show the relationship,it suits my purpose very clearly but the problem is that when i hover on a certain node in this api it shows only the relationship with its current neighbor. But i need to show the whole relationship in this graph when i hover on that,i.e each node will show the relationship with its immediate neighbor and also with the previous one.can anyone help me to do that???

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */
.link10 {
stroke: #000;
stroke-width: 2px;
stroke-dasharray: 3, 3;
}

.link1 {
stroke: #000;
stroke-width: 2px;
}

.nodetext {
pointer-events: none;
}

   .node.type1 {
fill: #690011;
    }

  .node.type2 {
fill: #BF0426;
   }

  .node.type3 {
fill: #E5B96F;
  }

    .node.type4 {
fill: #FFFFFF;
stroke: #1695A3;
stroke-width: 3px;
 }

.node.type5 {
fill: #1BC9E0;
}

.node.type6 {
fill: #E01B98;
}

image.circle {
cursor: pointer;
}

.fadein {
display: none;
font-size: 20px;
}

  .rectD {
background-color: #000000;
width: 70px;
height: 30px
  }

  .rectL {
background-color: #000000;
width: 90px;
height: 30px
   }
  </style>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
<script>
    var data = {
        "nodes" : [ {
            "name" : "JEET",
            "full_name" : "Yahoo",
            "type" : 5,
            "slug" : "www.yahoo.com",
            "entity" : "company",
            "img_hrefD" : "",
            "img_hrefL" : ""
        }, {
            "name" : "SATISH",
            "full_name" : "Google",
            "type" : 2,
            "slug" : "www.google.com",
            "entity" : "company",
            "img_hrefD" : "",
            "img_hrefL" : ""
        }, {
            "name" : "RAHUL",
            "full_name" : "Bing",
            "type" : 6,
            "slug" : "www.bing.com",
            "entity" : "company",
            "img_hrefD" : "",
            "img_hrefL" : ""
        }, {
            "name": "DANIEL",
            "full_name":"Yandex",
            "type":2,
            "slug":"www.yandex.com",
            "entity":"company",
            "img_hrefD":"",
            "img_hrefL":""
        },

        {
            "name" : "Desc1",
            "type" : 4,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "description"
        }, {
            "name" : "Desc2",
            "type" : 4,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "description"
        }, {
            "name" : "Desc4",
            "type" : 4,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "description"
        },

        {
            "name" : "SHYAM",
            "prefix" : "Mr.",
            "fst_name" : "Jim",
            "snd_name" : "Bean",
            "type" : 1,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "employee"
        }, {
            "name" : "PETER",
            "prefix" : "Ms.",
            "fst_name" : "Jenna",
            "snd_name" : "Jameson",
            "type" : 3,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "employee"
        }, {
            "name" : "ALEX",
            "prefix" : "Mr.",
            "fst_name" : "Lucky",
            "snd_name" : "Luke",
            "type" : 3,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "employee"
        }, {
            "name" : "MURFY",
            "prefix" : "Ms.",
            "fst_name" : "Pamela",
            "snd_name" : "Anderson",
            "type" : 1,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "employee"
        }, {
            "name" : "JENIFER",
            "prefix" : "Mr.",
            "fst_name" : "Nacho",
            "snd_name" : "Vidal",
            "type" : 3,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "employee"
        },



        {
            "name" : "Desc5",
            "type" : 4,
            "slug" : "",
            "entity" : "description"
        }, ],
        "links" : [ {
            "source" : 0,
            "target" : 4,
            "value" : 1,
            "distance" : 5
        }, {
            "source" : 0,
            "target" : 5,
            "value" : 1,
            "distance" : 5
        }, {
            "source" : 0,
            "target" : 6,
            "value" : 1,
            "distance" : 5
        },

        {
            "source" : 1,
            "target" : 4,
            "value" : 1,
            "distance" : 5
        }, {
            "source" : 2,
            "target" : 5,
            "value" : 1,
            "distance" : 5
        }, {
            "source" : 3,
            "target" : 6,
            "value" : 1,
            "distance" : 5
        },

        {
            "source" : 7,
            "target" : 3,
            "value" : 10,
            "distance" : 6
        }, {
            "source" : 8,
            "target" : 3,
            "value" : 10,
            "distance" : 6
        }, {
            "source" : 9,
            "target" : 1,
            "value" : 10,
            "distance" : 6
        }, {
            "source" : 10,
            "target" : 1,
            "value" : 10,
            "distance" : 6
        },

        {
            "source" : 11,
            "target" : 12,
            "value" : 10,
            "distance" : 6
        }, {
            "source" : 12,
            "target" : 2,
            "value" : 10,
            "distance" : 6
        }, ]
    };

    var w = 560, h = 500, radius = d3.scale.log().domain([0,312000 ])
            .range([ "10", "50" ]);

    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr(
            "height", h);

    vis.append("marker")
    .attr("id", "arrowhead")
    .attr("refX", 6 + 3) /*must be smarter way to calculate shift*/
    .attr("refY", 2)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 4)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z"); //this is actual shape for arrowhead


      // var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(nodes).links(links).charge(-3000)
        //  .friction(0.6).gravity(0.6).size([ width, height ]).start();




    //d3.json(data, function(json) {
    var force = self.force = d3.layout.force().nodes(data.nodes).links(
            data.links).linkDistance(function(d) {
        return (d.distance * 10);
    })
    //.friction(0.5)
    .charge(-250).size([ w, h ]).start();

    var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(data.links).enter().append(
            "svg:line").attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link" + d.value + "";
    }).attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
    }).attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
    }).attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
    }).attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
    }).attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        if (d.value == 1) {
            return "url(#arrowhead)"
        } else {
            return " "
        }
        ;
    });

    function openLink() {
        return function(d) {
            var url = "";
            if (d.slug != "") {
                url = d.slug
            } else if(d.type == 2) {
            url = "clients/" + d.slug
            } else if(d.type == 3) {
            url = "agencies/" + d.slug
            }
            window.open("//" + url)
        }
    }

    var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(data.nodes).enter().append(
            "svg:g").attr("class", "node").call(force.drag);

    node.append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
        return "node type" + d.type
    }).attr("r", function(d) {
        if (d.entity == "description") {
            return 6
        } else {
            return 18
        }
    })


    node.append("text").attr("class", function(d) {
        return "nodetext title_" + d.name
    }).attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em").style("font-size", "10px").attr(
            "text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white").text(
            function(d) {
                if (d.entity != "description") {
                    return d.name
                }
            });

    node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        if (d.entity == "company") {
            d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.full_name;
                    }).style("font-size", "15px")

        } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
            var asdf = d3.select(this);
            asdf.select('text').remove();

            asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                return d.prefix + ' ' + d.fst_name
            }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .style("font-size", "5px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");

            asdf.append("text").text(function(d) {
                return d.snd_name
            }).attr("class", "nodetext").attr("transform",
                    "translate(0, 12)").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .style("font-size", "5px")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .transition().duration(300).style("font-size", "12px");
        } else {
            d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "15px")
        }

        if (d.entity == "company") {
            d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "90px").attr("x",
                    "-46px").attr("y", "-36.5px").attr("xlink:href",
                    function(d) {
                        return d.img_hrefL
                    });
        }

        if (d.entity == "company") {

            d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 28)

        } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
            d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 32)
        }
    });

    node.on("mouseout", function(d) {
        if (d.entity == "company") {
            d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300).text(
                    function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }).style("font-size", "10px")
        } else if (d.entity == "employee") {
            ///////////////////////////
            // CHANGE
            ///////////////////////////

            d3.select(this).selectAll('text').remove();

            //d3.select(this).select('text')
            d3.select(this).append('text').text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
            }).style("font-size", "14px").attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("fill", "white")
                    .attr("class", "nodetext").transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "10px")

        } else {
            d3.select(this).select('text').transition().duration(300)
                    .style("font-size", "10px")
        }

        if (d.entity == "company") {
            d3.select(this).select('image').attr("width", "70px").attr("x",
                    "-36px").attr("y", "-36px").attr("xlink:href",
                    function(d) {
                        return d.img_hrefD
                    });
        }

        if (d.entity == "company" || d.entity == "employee") {

            d3.select(this).select('circle').transition().duration(300)
                    .attr("r", 18)
        }

    });

    node.on("mouseover", fade(.4, "red")).on("mouseout", fade(1));

    var linkedByIndex = {};
    data.links.forEach(function(d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
    });

    function isConnected(a, b) {
        return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index]
                || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index]
                || a.index == b.index;
    }

    force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        }).attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        }).attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        }).attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    });

    function fade(opacity, color) {
        return function(d) {

            node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                return thisOpacity;
            });

            link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
            })

            .style("stroke", function(o) {
                return o.source === d || o.target === d ? color : "#000";
            });
        };

    }
    //});
</script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

i want a direction of the arrows of incoming and that of outgoing

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154129/d3js-force-directed-graph-advanced-highlighting-of-neigbour-nodes-and-links)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff this example is useful can i define my own size  for each node here???

Comment: Not sure what you mean by size, but the answer is almost certainly yes.

Comment: ok lars i will try to do that.but can you tell me one thing that,in this example i can see 3 levels.can i make the color same for level 0 and level 2 and so on i.e all even levels are of same color and all odd levels are same color

Comment: You would need to pass another argument to your recursive call that gets the connected nodes that determines whether the level is odd or even. You can store that with the data and then set the colour based on that.

Comment: can you give me just a hint please

Comment: Could you post a complete example of what you're trying to do and where you're struggling please?

Comment: thanks for your reply Lars i have changed the color of the nodes i want, with your idea.i just stuck to an issue that i want a direction of the arrows i.e which is incoming and outgoing.i am posting my full code for you ..see if you can help...

Comment: @LarsKotthoff anyway thanks for helping me continuously

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/egV7h/) what you're looking for? It's currently doing two levels, you can adjust by changing the number in line 304.