# Highlight a node and its neighbour node in force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a force directed graph using `D3.JS` Library,

On `mouseover` what I would like to do is to highlight a node and its neighbour node and fade away all other nodes.

On `mouseout` event I want to reset the graph like the way it is.

I have tried the following code for the highlight part but its not working:

```
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { 

d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 6);
var nodeNeighbors = graph.links.filter(function(link) {

 return link.source.index === d.index || link.target.index === d.index;})
                        .map(function(link) {

 return link.source.index === d.index ? link.target.index : link.source.index; });
```

Following is the[link for my force directed graph](http://plnkr.co/edit/d3a92HOodd7lQdPr6wQd?p=preview)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-force-directed-grap) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154129/d3js-force-directed-graph-advanced-highlighting-of-neigbour-nodes-and-links) may help.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have updated my code with the following examples but still its not working. http://plnkr.co/edit/d3a92HOodd7lQdPr6wQd?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost a complete copy and paste from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-force-directed-grap), see there for the explanation of the details.

The only things I have changed is to fade the nodes/links out/in with a transition and added connections in both directions to the data structure that is used to determine the neighbours. Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3fv3IR3S3Kp86rAummnz?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

It might turn out easier if you fork this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCi4kFyVk3IQMpILzXQ6?p=preview) and study the main piece:

```
var linkedByIndex = {};
    json.links.forEach(function(d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
}
```