# How to find edges point to a particular node?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am in the process of implementing a directed graph visualization using a d3.js force-directed layout. See: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5155181

My problem is that I am trying to get the paths that are pointing towards a node but I have no idea how to get started.

Also, I am having trouble understanding how arrow heads are attached in the first place:

```
   // build the arrow.
   svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

   // add the links and the arrows
   var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers are attached by this line:

```
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

This is saying that the marker at the end of the path (i.e. the node it is pointing to) should be decorated with the marker defined with ID "end" -- the arrow in the `defs` section.

To find the edges pointing to a node, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-js-force-directed-g) should be helpful. The idea is to iterate over all the links and check whether they are associated with the current node, in your case whether it is the target. The code for this would look something like this (as a mouseover handler).

```
node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  var pointing = links.filter(function(e) { return e.target == d; });
});
```

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you very much for your explanation! Very helpful! Just a quick question, what does "url(#end)" mean? The reason I'm asking is because I also want to get the arrowhead assigned to the specific link. I've checked the HTML and the arrowhead doesn't seem to be a child of the <path> element.

Comment: The `url(#end)` means "find the element in the `defs` section with ID end".