# Force layout link highlight between two nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highlight, force-layout

How can I put in a feature such that all the possible links between two nodes in a d3 force layout is highlighted(say the user makes two selections via mouse click)?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-force-directed-grap)?

Comment: yes, this just highlight all the related links to the single node(on hover). Instead I want all the possible paths highlighted between two nodes selected(by mouse click).

Comment: This would be entire connected component the two nodes are contained in, no? I.e. all possible paths would cover all nodes connected to the two.

Comment: No, that won't be the case, as the links have direction.

Comment: This may help: http://blogs.nonado.net/sammi/2013/01/13/code-snippet-paths-between-two-nodes/