# Manipulating d3 network diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, diagram

I have a question regarding d3 network diagram. Say I have a simple, one like here in my jsFiddle [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/122/) , diagram.And Id like to have a function, for example that deletes the middle circle and connects the first and the third one. Could someone please assist me on this ?

```
[['L1', 'L2'], ['L2', 'L3']]
```

Probably its not gonna be 'hard delete', but hiding or not showing ? Because also Id like to know a way how could i bring that middle, deleted circle back and the original diagram back.

Ideally i would love someone to assist me with some snippets of two functions which one would delete the middle circle and the other one (say by pressing a button) would bring it back.

Also we could make an assumption that each circle has an id  and the connections between them would have Ids as well, if that makes stuff easier of course.

Comment: Have a look at those links : [Modifying a Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) & [How to highlight neighbors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-force-directed-grap)

Comment: Thats not really talking about how to filter nodes, I actually found an example yesterday [link](http://viroscope.info/#/collapse5) , in the accordion on the left if you select genome length, You'd get a slider which would filter directly the graph on the left. thats exactly what im after how to filter the nodes based on its properties, for example size.