# Get reference to links featuring a given node using D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have some pretty standard code that creates a bunch of SVG:circles based on `node` data and SVG:lines based on `link` data.

I want to put some rollover code on the circles and lines such that rolling over a circle highlights that circle, the lines that connect to it, and any other circles at the end of those lines.

The challenge I'm having is getting a reference to the `link` data when I'm handling an event triggered by the circle, which only has `node` datum attached.

```
d3nodes = d3svg.selectAll( ".node" )
    .data( nodes )
    .enter().append( "circle" )
        .attr( "class", "node" )
        .attr( "r", NODE_RADIUS )
        .attr( "cx", function( d ){ return d.x; } )
        .attr( "cy", function( d ){ return d.y; } )
        .on( "mouseover", function( d ){ console.log( d ); } ); // Node datum

d3links = d3svg.selectAll( ".link" )
    .data( links )
    .enter().append( "line" )
        .attr( "class", "link" )
        .attr( "x1", function( d ){ return nodes[d.source].x; } )
        .attr( "y1", function( d ){ return nodes[d.source].y; } )
        .attr( "x2", function( d ){ return nodes[d.target].x; } )
        .attr( "y2", function( d ){ return nodes[d.target].y; } )
        .on( "mouseover", function( d ){ console.log( d ); } ); // Link datum
```

Once I have a reference to `links`, I can use the following function to get a list of links where that node is either a source or a target:

```
/**
 * Gets up to 4 nodes, that represent all the nodes linked to this node
 * (either as targets or source).
 *
 * @param {Object} node Object from the "nodes" array (so, the data, not the d3nodes)
 * @param {Object[]} links Array of links (again, the data that was passed to the force layout)
 * @returns {Array} Matching node objects (again, not DOM elements)
 */
function getLinks( node, links ){
    var nodes = [],
        i = 0, l = links.length,
        link;

    for ( ; i < l; ++i ){
        link = links[i];
        if ( link.target === node ){
            nodes.push( link.source );
            continue;
        }

        if ( link.source === node ){
            nodes.push( link.target );
        }
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

But my function really needs a reference to the `links` array, and I'm not sure how to get it from within an event handler that only seems to get the `node` datum.

I'd like to avoid any kind of global variables, or a global lookup table, since I'm going to have any number of these graphs on a page, and they all need to stay separate.

In the past I've stored a reference to the `nodes`, `links` and `force` objects on the DOM element itself (using jQuery.data()), but is that really a best practice?

I feel like I'm missing an important conceptual point, and hope someone can shed some light.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739072/highlight-selected-node-its-links-and-its-children-in-a-d3-force-directed-grap)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I had not, and I'm surprised it didn't come up in a search or suggestion - my Google-fu must be weak today. Mike's answer deals more with the performance of the link lookup as opposed to accessing / scoping of the link and node data, so I think there's overlap, but distinction between the two questions.

Comment: Well it gives a way of doing what you're trying to do, right? As in, you could use that approach to make it work? I may be missing how your problem is different and why this approach doesn't apply.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff you're not wrong :) However, I'm not sure it completely addresses my situation, because I'm running any number of similar (but distinct) graphs on the same page. So I would need some sort of global structure that linked a particular graph to a list of nodes and links. I'm leaning toward adding a reference to the links within the node record (laughing in the face of the circular references this will cause)!

Comment: Ok, I see. Yes, I think attaching link information to the node datum is the way to go then.